# Problems with using bibtex on Texshop on Mac. Gives error " I couldn't open file name `references.aux' "

Tags: bibliographies

Since I started my bibliography, I had to get a new laptop. When I tried to make additions to my bibliography which was working before, I get this error

I couldn't open file name `references.aux'

This is AFTER trying to compile as a tex document, and then I get this error when I try to compile as a bib document. It is not generating the .aux document that it is supposed to when I try to compile it as a tex document.

Has anyone encountered this before and have a fix?

Comment: Are you loading `biblatex` to create the bibliography (since you added the `biblatex` tag.) If  so you need to use `biber` to not `bibtex`. By default, TeXShop uses `bibtex` to process `.bib` files. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751) for how to do this.

Comment: You do not compile the `.bib`, i.e. you should not run  BibTeX (or Biber) on your `.bib` file. You should run BibTeX/Biber on the base name (i.e. the name without file extension) of your main `.tex` file. Assuming your document is called `mydoc.tex`, you need to run `pdflatex mydoc`, `bibtex mydoc`, `pdflatex mydoc`, `pdlfatex mydoc` (of course `pdflatex` can be replaced by your favourite flavour of LaTeX: `lualatex`, `xelatex`, ...). The file name of your `.bib` file is irrelevant for that. In your editor that means that you should click compile only with the main `.tex` file in focus.

Comment: @moewe I think the issue is with the tool. TeXshop knows how to process a bibliography properly although I guess it’s possible that the code in the document is just wrong. I used the term “process the .bib file” very informally.

Comment: @AlanMunn The file name in ```I couldn't open file name `references.aux'``` made me suspect this is a 'you compiled the wrong file problem': People often call their `.bib` files `references.bib`, but usually the main `.tex` file is not called `references.tex`. I wouldn't have expected the message ```I couldn't open `references.aux'``` in case of a BibTeX/Biber mixup. Biber would complain about a missing `.bcf` file and BibTeX would complain `I found no \citation commands` etc. If you call the bib tool, LaTeX must have been run and the aux present.

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't think I did load biblatex. I assumed that was the correct tag but now you have me doubting it.

Comment: @moewe I don't completely understand your comment, but I made some guesses as to what you were saying and magically it worked! Thanks a lot.